# move_uploaded_file no funciona o no sube archivos con php

Tags: php

Estamos tratando se subir una foto al servidor, pero al parecer move_uploaded_file no funciona, dicho servidor es un Ubuntu server ya se dio permisos de escritura, pero igual no funciona, estamos dejando parte del código, nos gustaría analicen y nos puedan ayudar, está en php y es un sistema de registro de mascotas… gracias

```
<form action="includes/templates/enviaregistra.php" id="formResgitra" 
name="registra" onsubmit="return        validar();" 
enctype="multipart/form- 
data" method="post" >

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-12">
                  <label for="foto-can">Foto de la mascota</label>
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input                          
                      type="file"                          
                      id="fotoMascotaRegistra"                          
                      name="foto"
                    />
                    <label                          
                      data-browse="Elegir archivo"
                      ></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-perro btn-block"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#modalRegistra"
                    value="registra"
                    id="btnregistra"
                  >
                    Enviar Solicitud
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

     <?php 
    include_once 'conexion.php';
    if (!$conexion) {
    die();
    }

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {
     $check = @getimagesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);
     if ($check !== false) {
       $carpeta_destino = 'fotos/';
       $archivo_subido = $carpeta_destino . $_FILES['foto']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: probá con `$carpeta_destino = __DIR__ . '/fotos/';`

Comment: No funciona ya lo probé, muchas gracias de todos modos..

Comment: Solucionado muchas gracias..

Comment: Oye amigo tengo el mismo problema podrías Compartir como fue que lo solucionaste!!

Comment: El problema no fue del código fue de Bootstrap que nos olvidamos de poner el ajax..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mira tengo una función hecha para manejar archivos de imagen no se si te sirva, me cuentas. Saludos.

```
public function ManejadorArchivo($archivo, $NombreCarpeta, $url) {
        $respuesta['status']     = "error";
        $respuesta['mensaje']    = "error";
        $respuesta['rutaimagen'] = "imagenes/web/Sin_Imagen.png";
        # Comienza Codigo Imagen
        if (trim($archivo['name']) != "") {
            # Si existe Imagen
            $extensionesPermitidas = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'PNG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG');
            $tipoArchivo = $archivo['type'];
            $comprobarTipo = preg_match('/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|gif|png|JPG|PNG)$/', $tipoArchivo);
            $extImg = explode('.', $archivo['name']);
            $extensionImagen = end($extImg);
            $comprobarExtension = in_array($extensionImagen, $extensionesPermitidas);
            $imgProducto = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0 , 10).'.'.$extensionImagen;
            $carpeta = $url.$this->LimpiarCarpeta($NombreCarpeta);
            if ($comprobarTipo) {
                if ($comprobarExtension) {
                    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
                        mkdir($carpeta, 0755, true);
                    }
                    $rutaImagen = $carpeta.'/'.$imgProducto;
                    while (file_exists($rutaImagen)) {
                        # Renombrar hasta que archivo no exista en la carpeta
                        $rutaImagen = $carpeta.'/'.substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), 0, 10))).'_'.$imgProducto;
                    }
                    $subirImagen = move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $rutaImagen);
                    if ($subirImagen) {
                        # Se subio con exito el archivo
                        $respuesta['status']     = "ok";
                        $respuesta['mensaje']    = "ok";
                        $respuesta['rutaimagen'] = $rutaImagen;
                    } else {
                        # Hubo un error al subir el archivo
                        $respuesta['mensaje'] = $archivo['error'];
                        // echo '<article class="box_contenedor_seccion_web tam-peque-margen tam-pequeu-margen tam-pequed-margen tam-medi-mitad tam-mediu-mitad tam-grande-mitad tam-grandeu-mitad bg_rojo txt_blanco box_form_mensaje"> <i class="fas fa-times"></i>Se produjo el siguiente error al subir la imagen, ( '.$errorImagen.' ).</article>';
                    }
                } else {
                    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "La extensión del archivo debe ser de tipo imagen.";
                }
            } else {
                $respuesta['mensaje'] = "El archivo debe ser de tipo imagen.";
            }
        } else {
            $respuesta['status']     = "ok";
            $respuesta['mensaje']    = "ok";
        }
        # Termina Codigo Imagen
        return $respuesta;
    }
```